# porque el contador se eleva tan rapido?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa que simula un NFA.Tengo la clase nfa,estado y transicion:

```
class nfa{

public:

    nfa(){}
    nfa(int a);
    void set_init(int a);
    estado* get_inicial(){
        return grafo[inicial];
    }
    estado* get_state_info(int a);

    bool analizar_cadena(string cadena,estado* actual);


private:
    vector<estado*> grafo;
    int inicial;
    int nestados;
    bool completado;


};



class estado{

public:
    estado();

    bool is_init();
    void set_aceptado(bool a );
    bool get_aceptado();
    void set_n_trans(int a);
    transicion& get_trans(int a);

    vector<int> search_next_state(char a);


private:
    vector<transicion> transiciones;
    bool iniciado;
    bool aceptacion;



};



class transicion{

public:

    transicion();
    void set(int a, char b);
    int get_state();
    bool check_cad(char a);


private:
    int estado;
    char cadena;

};
```

el programa lee desde un fichero la estructura del nfa (cosa que hace bien, ya que lo compruebo haciendo que muestre el resultado de diversas operaciones). El problema lo tengo cuando intento analizar una cadena:

La cadena entra por el siguiente metodo:

```
bool nfa::analizar_cadena(string cadena,estado* actual){
cout<<"cadena: "<<cadena<<endl;
char fail;
//actual=grafo[inicial];
int siguiente=-1;
vector <int> recorrido;


recorrido=actual->search_next_state('~');

if(recorrido.size()!=0){
    for(int i=0;i<=recorrido.size() && completado==false;i++)
        analizar_cadena(cadena,grafo[recorrido[i]]);
}

recorrido.clear();

recorrido=actual->search_next_state(cadena[0]);

if(recorrido.size()==0)
    fail=cadena[0];

if(recorrido.size()!=0){
    cadena.erase(0,1);
    for(int i=0;i<=recorrido.size() && completado==false;i++){
        cout<<"siguiente : "<<recorrido[i]<<endl;

        analizar_cadena(cadena,grafo[recorrido[i]]);
    }
}

if(cadena=="" && actual->get_aceptado()==true)
    completado=true;    

return completado;
}
```

Como se ve, lo que hice fue hacer la busqueda por recursividad, de ahi se pasa al metodo search_next_state(..):

```
vector<int> estado::search_next_state(char a){
    vector<int> salidas;
    salidas.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<=transiciones.size();i++){

        if(transiciones[i].check_cad(a)==true){
            cout<<"obtenemos para la cadena "<<a<<" , el esatado: "<<transiciones[i].get_state()<<endl; 
            salidas.push_back(transiciones[i].get_state());

        }
    }
    cout<<" hay "<<salidas.size()<< "transiciones con la cadena: "<<a<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<=salidas.size() && !salidas.empty();i++){
        cout<<salidas[i]<<endl;
    }
    return salidas;
}
```

por ultimo cabe resaltar el metodo check_cad(..), que se encarga de comprobar si una cadena coincide con la cadena correspondiente con la transicion a la que representa:

```
bool transicion::check_cad(char a){

    return (cadena==a);
}
```

en el siguiente ejemplo que uso para comprobar su funcionamiento tengo el siguiente nfa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento analizar, por ejemoplo la cadena "bba", que deberia de ser aceptada ya que : 0->1->2->3

tengo el siguiente resultado:

```
cadena: bba
  hay 0transiciones con la cadena: ~
 obtenemos para la cadena b , el esatado: 0
 hay 1transiciones con la cadena: b
 0           <-- estos son supuestamente los estados de las transiciones de cada estado
 0
 siguiente : 0
 cadena: ba
  hay 0transiciones con la cadena: ~
 obtenemos para la cadena b , el esatado: 0
  hay 1transiciones con la cadena: b
 0
 32635
 siguiente : 0
 cadena: a
  hay 0transiciones con la cadena: ~
 obtenemos para la cadena a , el esatado: 0
 hay 1transiciones con la cadena: a
0
32635
 siguiente : 0
 cadena: 
  hay 0transiciones con la cadena: ~
  hay 0transiciones con la cadena: 
 siguiente : 32635
 Violación de segmento
```

Como se ve : sale "siguiente: 32635" y no se porque se eleva tanto el contador de transiciones

Comment: Con el código que pones es complicado decirte. Solo puedo decirte que revises aquellas funciones que pueden modificar el estado de las transiciones... el código que muestras no incluye dichas funciones ni sus usos...

Comment: el tema es que cuando se analiza la cadena no se hace ningun tipo de modificacion sobre las transiciones, solo se "leen", pudiese poner el resultado de la lectura del fichero para que se viese todo al momento de "crear" el nfa, pero creo que ya seria bastante....

Comment: Da igual, no tienes funciones ni parámetros `const`, así que en algún sitio se están modificando los objetos. Pon puntos de parada o pon un ejemplo mínimo y completo que verifique el problema

Comment: vale, creo que hare lo de los `const`, lo del ejemplo minimo y completo lo tengo un poco complicado XD

Comment: Si crees que no estás modificando nada, pero resulta que sí, mira a ver que no tengas por ahi una comparación que deberia ser `==` pero has puesto un solo `=`. Por otro lado, en el código que muestras se ve dónde inicializas `siguiente` y cómo en el bucle la imprimes (donde imprimes, por cierto `recorrido[i]` en lugar de `siguiente`), pero no se ve la parte de código donde se actualiza el valor de ésta última.

Comment: si, es una pifia, `siguiente` es una variable inutil, ya la quite, creo que el error esta en el vector de transiciones `vector<transiciones>` , pues cuando me puse a ver cuantas transiciones tenia guardada cada estado, habian algunos que les faltaba, por ejemplo, el primero aparecia que tenia 2, sin embargo, podia acceder "manualmente" al tercer elemento y ... resulta que si existia, con lo cual lo estoy cambiando para que trabaje con punteros `vector<transiciones*>`

Comment: ya lo solucionem,o eso parece, en el metodo `nfa::analizar_cadena(....)` en el bucle que recorre para insertar las cadenas no vacias, puse como condicion `i<=recorrido.size()`, que teniendo en cuenta que recorrido pertenece a la clase `std::vector`, devuelve el numero sin contar el 0, con lo cual accedia a una posicion que no existia

Comment: El ejemplo es complicado. Compílalo con Visual Studio y utiliza un "Data Breakpoint", así puedes ver exactamente cuándo cualquier variable es modificada, y hasta puedes ponerle condiciones, como que sólo se detenga cuando a la variable se le asigne un valor muy grande, como algún valor mayor a 30000.